# Pytest setup generate product for all test

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, pytest

I am working on pytest API automation project, and I need to get a random product from the DB. Is there a way that I could use the same random product for all the test cases in my class? I am using a setup class method but it generates a different product every test. Thank you.

```
class TestCreateOrdersSmoke:

@classmethod
def setup(cls):
    cls.products_db = ProductsDao()
    cls.orders_db = OrdersDao()
    cls.orders_helper = OrdersHelper()


@pytest.mark.tcid48
def test_create_order_as_guest(self):
    random_product = self.products_db.select_random_product_from_db()
    random_product_id = random_product[0]['ID']
```

UPDATE:

So i used a pytest session fixture like seggested and it works so thank you! but i want to make sure that this is right practice so here is the updated code:

```
class TestCreateOrdersSmoke:

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def helpers(self):
    products_db = ProductsDao()
    orders_db = OrdersDao()
    orders_helper = OrdersHelper()
    random_product = products_db.select_random_product_from_db()
    yield {'products_db':products_db,
           'orders_db':orders_db,
           'orders_helper':orders_helper,
           'random_product':random_product}

@pytest.mark.tcid48
def test_create_order_as_guest(self, helpers):
    random_product = helpers['random_product']
    random_product_id = random_product[0]['ID']

@pytest.mark.tcid88
def test_create_order_with_new_user(self, helpers):

    random_product = helpers['random_product']
    random_product_id = random_product[0]['ID']
```

Comment: Use a [session-scoped fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you need a fixture for all methods in class, so you can use "class" or "session" scope fixture `@pytest.fixture(scope="class")`.

Here some ways to organize the code with the "class" or "session" fixtures.

First way: fixture with `"class"` scope can be inside a `class`, example is the same as you did with "session" fixture:

```
class TestCreateOrdersSmoke:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
```

Second way: fixture with "class" scope can be outside of the class, so then you can use it in different classes, example:

```
import logging


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def h():
    logging.info('h')
 

class TestOne:
    def test_one_one(self, h):
        logging.info('test_one_one')

    def test_one_two(self, h):
        logging.info('test_one_two')


class TestTwo:
    def test_two_one(self, h):
        logging.info('test_two_one')
```

Third way: you can annotate `class` with a fixture by marking `@pytest.mark.usefixtrures('fixture_name')` and you don't need to pass fixture to each method of the class, it will be passed automatically. Example:

```
import logging


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def h():
    logging.info('h')
 

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('h')
class TestOne:
    def test_one_one(self):
        logging.info('test_one_one')

    def test_one_two(self):
        logging.info('test_one_two')
```

And you can try to use `'autouse'` fixture param, so you don't need to pass fixture inside methods, or annotate class with it. Example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def h():
    logging.info('h')
 

class TestOne:
    def test_one_one(self):
        logging.info('test_one_one')

    def test_one_two(self):
        logging.info('test_one_two')
```

But i don't recommend to use `autouse`, be aware from use it.

Comment: @test_junkie123 hope it helps you. And you it's not necessary to use "session" scope fixture if fixture is inside the class, "class" scope will be enough and more clear.